# Forgot the Title - Matriarchal society - woman renews marriage contract?

Tags: story-identification, books

There was a book I read in the 90s or 2000s - it was about a boy coming of age - his father was married to a woman of high status in their society and she renewed his marriage contract with him repeatedly.

The boy meets his sister (but I don't think he knows its his sister initially)

I also maybe remember something about a horse initially in the book and the boy thinking that he disappointed his father somehow?

Comment: What are science fiction or fantasy elements in the book?